# AngularJS TypeError: randomQuotes.getAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve a random quote from a web api using AngularJS.However am getting this error ' TypeError: randomQuotes.getAll is not a function  at b.getQuotes (controller.js:18) '.How do i resolve this error ?.  I have commented the line that the error points to.

factory.js

```
angular.module('quotesService', ['ngResource']).
factory('randomQuotes', [
    '$resource',

    function ($resource) {

        return $resource('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?',

            {
                getAll: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    params: { }
                }
            });
    }

]);
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('ApiController', [
    '$scope','$timeout','$q','$http','randomQuotes',

    function($scope,$timeout,$q,$http,randomQuotes) {

        $scope.model = {
           number: 0,
           result: 'Ready',
        };

        $scope.getQuotes = getQuotes;

        function getQuotes() {

            $scope.model.quotes = randomQuotes.getAll(); //error points to this line (line 18)
        }

    }
])
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',[
    'ngResource',
    'quotesService'

]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app = "app">
<head>

</head>

<body ng-controller= "ApiController">
    <div class = "container">
            <div><input type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Get Quote" ng-click="getQuotes()"/></div>

            <div class = "quote" ng-repeat="quote in model.quotes">

                <p>quote.title</p>
                <p>quote.content</p>

            </div>


    </div>



    <script src  = "js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src  = "js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src =  "factory.js"></script>
    <script src =  "app.js"></script>
    <script src =  "controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your factory as follows,

```
angular.module('quotesService', ['ngResource']) 
    .factory('randomQuotes', function($resource) {      
        return $resource('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?', {}, {
            getAll: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}     
        });
    });
```